# Store all Twilio message media links into an array

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

How can I store all Twilio message media links into an array?

My current implementation is

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback)  {

//...

var mediaUrls = [];

for (var i = 0; i < event.NumMedia; i++) { 
  var m = eval("(typeof event.MediaUrl"+i+" !== 'undefined')? event.MediaUrl"+i+" : ''");
  if (m !== '') mediaUrls.push(m);
}

//...

}
```

But using `eval` is not a good practice, because

> eval can be harmful.

Is there some other solution to do that, without using `eval`?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Instead of using `eval` and dot notation to call on each media URL you can use square bracket notation. So instead of what you had you could do the following:

```
var mediaUrls = [];

for (var i = 0; i < event.NumMedia; i++) { 
  if (typeof event["MediaUrl"+i] !== 'undefined') {
     mediaUrls.push(event["MediaUrl"+i]);
  }
}
```

Let me know if that helps at all.